# Mysql specific returned value always like last row

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

It is possible have some specific value always like last row? For example:

```
SELECT IF(paCountry.NAME IS NULL,'Unknown',paCountry.NAME) AS countryName
FROM Table
ORDER BY paCountry.NAME
```

This return some values like:
A
B
**Unknown**
C
D

And a want to have always "Unknown" like a last returned row.
so this shoud look like:
A
B
C
D
**Unknown**

Comment: ORDER BY countryname = 'unknown'

Comment: Does that query really sort null values in the middle?

Comment: Tip of today: `coalesce(paCountry.NAME, 'Unknown') AS countryName`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `CASE` in `ORDER BY`:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN countryName = 'Unknown' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, countryName
```

Answer (score 2):

By default MySQL sorts null values first (when ascending order). But you can use `IS NULL` to sort them last:

```
ORDER BY paCountry.NAME IS NULL, paCountry.NAME
```

And use `COALESCE` to replace null values with 'Unknown':

```
SELECT COALESCE(paCountry.NAME, 'Unknown') AS countryName
FROM Table
ORDER BY paCountry.NAME IS NULL, paCountry.NAME
```

Comment: "Since MySQL sorts null values first" MySQL seams to be doing that only when you use `ASC` but not when using `DESC` see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/RziGyyhy3gM4qPwVpAZt1/0).. the results are the same between MySQL versions

Comment: @RaymondNijland, correct, but OP still wants the cities with non-null names in ASC order.

Comment: i know i commented because future readers also might have gotten the idea that it counted for ASC and DESC sorting orders.